# What is the best way to top k pool elements instead of only the max one in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Now the max pooling function in tensorflow is

```
tf.nn.max_pool(value, ksize, strides, padding, name=None)
Returns:
A Tensor with type tf.float32. The max pooled output tensor.
```

I would like to have an extend version of max_pool, like

```
tf.nn.top_k_pool(value, ksize, strides, padding, k=1, name=None)

Performs the top k pooling on the input.

Args:

value: A 4-D Tensor with shape [batch, height, width, channels] and type tf.float32.
ksize: A list of ints that has length >= 4. The size of the window for each dimension of the input tensor.
strides: A list of ints that has length >= 4. The stride of the sliding window for each dimension of the input tensor.
padding: A string, either 'VALID' or 'SAME'. The padding algorithm.
k: 0-D int32 Tensor. Number of top elements to look in each pool.
name: Optional name for the operation.
Returns:

A Tensor with type tf.float32. The max pooled output tensor. There will be an additional dimension saving the top k values.
```

I know that I can expend the tensorflow operation following https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html

I would like to know if there is an easier way to achieve that.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function to using `top_k`to take the max k activations of the channels. You can modify it to fit your purpose:

```
def make_sparse_layer(inp_x,k, batch_size=None):

    in_shape = tf.shape(inp_x)
    d = inp_x.get_shape().as_list()[-1]
    matrix_in = tf.reshape(inp_x, [-1,d])
    values, indices = tf.nn.top_k(matrix_in, k=k, sorted=False)
    out = []
    vals = tf.unpack(values, axis=0, num=batch_size)
    inds = tf.unpack(indices, axis=0, num=batch_size)
    for i, idx in enumerate(inds):
        out.append(tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(tf.SparseTensor(tf.reshape(tf.cast(idx,tf.int64),[-1,1]),vals[i], [d]), validate_indices=False ))
    shaped_out = tf.reshape(tf.pack(out), in_shape)
    return shaped_out
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably the TopK op: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html#top_k

Comment: Could you show a piece of code to implement it?
In fact, I've looked that function but I cannot image a way to implement it as pooling, because I have to deal with the pool window.

Answer (score 1):

usd tf.reshape(), tf.matrix_transpose(), tf.nn.top_k(sorted=False), and the 'data_format' argument in tf.nn.conv2d(), see http://www.infocool.net/kb/OtherCloud/201703/318346.html for details