# Is it possible to implement a max pooling layer in Keras which provides the maximum n values from a given pool size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a multidimensional time series dataset which has the following shape (n_samples, 512, 9) where 512 is the timesteps and 9 are the channels.

After the first 1D  CNN layer with 64 kernels my output shape is (n_samples, 512, 64). Now I would like to have my input to next layer which is an LSTM to be of the shape (n_samples, 384, 64).

It can be achieved if I have a Maxpool layer that returns maximum 3 values from pool size of 4 but is it possible to implement this in Keras?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably solve this with a [`keras.layers.Lambda`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layer, and the backend to [`tf.nn.in_top_k`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/672a873ffb344dfa030103cad69bdbc948184e8e/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py). Note that the [handling is somewhat different](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/in_top_k) from `tf.nn.top_k`, in that it does not pool if all the values are of the same value!

Now you can define yourself a function that returns the top `k` values (and does so 
somewhat efficiently), and then pass it as a function to the lambda layer.

I sadly haven't worked enough with Keras to type out the specific code, but maybe this is help enough to point you in the right direction.
Also, there exists a similar thread [for TensorFlow specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272502/what-is-the-best-way-to-top-k-pool-elements-instead-of-only-the-max-one-in-tenso).